# Sendgrid doesn't trigger webhook when email is sent

Tags: webhooks, sendgrid, ngrok

I'm using Sendgrid in an ASP.NET WEB API project, and I'm testing the webhook call with ngrok.

I first followed this guide: https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/tracking-events/getting-started-event-webhook

Therefore i turned on Event Webhook and tested it with their integration test.

The problem is that it works only during test, if I send an email with my software, webhook is not fired. ( I receive the email, but Ngrok doesn't record a request)

This is how i send the email:

```
var client = new SendGridClient(Config.sendGridApiKey);
var x = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail( new EmailAddress(Config.mymail),
    new EmailAddress(to), content, content, content);
return await client.SendEmailAsync(x).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't choose the event triggering the webhook from the panel.

Now it works!

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/31753886)

Comment: I updated the answer, i think it was not clear I resolved in that easy way.